# Consistent crashing of FTL

Tags: technical-issues, ftl-faster-than-light, linux

Whenever I play the game Faster Than Light (or FTL), my game experiences random crashes. Preceding the crash, the sound of my game will turn into a very pixellated, choppy sound that sounds like a corrupted sound file of some kind, followed by slowed-down gameplay.

Sometimes, it will resolve itself after 20 minutes or so and return to normal speeds, other times, my window will freeze completely and the game crashes.

I check the output of my terminal on my Linux laptop, and the output it gives can be seen [here](http://newpaste.md-5.net/prccaxynh).

Ultimately, I just want to know **what is causing the crash and how can I fix it?**

***Edit #1***: Link fixed, you are able to see the crash log now!

***Edit #2***: During the startup process of the game, it throws a few errors, which you can see [here](http://newpaste.md-5.net/p7qaj0evk). See lines 5, 6, and 8.

***Edit #3***: After doing the fix described by @allquixotic and replacing the `libbass.so` file with one from the developer's website, I still crashed. The latest crash log can be seen [here](http://newpaste.md-5.net/pxkykfkv5).

***Edit #4***: Still experiencing severe crashes. See additional crashlogs [here](http://newpaste.md-5.net/pbdktzygg).

Comment: Sorry, but your link says "You are not authorized to access this resource."

Comment: The console output would be useful; `dmesg` would be useful too. The choppy sound suggests it might be an issue with ALSA or PulseAudio or OpenAL, although it could be an artifact of stack or heap corruption, which could either just be a coding error in the game, or a problem with something else (most likely the graphics driver).

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Sorry, accidentally marked it as a private paste. You should be able to see the console output now!

Comment: @allquixotic I think I remember seeing something about stack / heap corruption in the log, but I'm unsure about the output. It should be viewable now!

Comment: edit your question to state the link was fixed

Comment: Did you get FTL through Steam or some other resource?

Comment: @espais I have the game just by itself, without Steam or anything along those lines. I start the game up with a script that I drag into my Terminal window.

Comment: Did anyone have any more ideas for how to resolve this issue? I know @allquixotic was thinking that my computer may just be too new for the game, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

The crash log suggests that libbassmix, part of the [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) audio framework, is responsible. BASS is *not* open source, unfortunately, so we will be unable to troubleshoot beyond the basics: try to download the latest version of BASS on their website, and replace the BASS version that the game uses with this version, by replacing the files `/home/jflory/Games/FTL/data/amd64/lib/libbassmix.so` and `/home/jflory/Games/FTL/data/amd64/lib/libbass.so` with the versions you downloaded.

BTW, there is a thread on the FTL official forums where a bunch of other users complained about the same thing. I'm rather surprised you didn't find this in your first search (you *did* search before asking a question, didn't you? :))) -- look [here](http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17208). There was a developer trying to get involved, and some people claimed they got it to work using a similar method to what I suggested.

Comment: I tried replacing the file, and no luck. The sound started playing extremely weird like it has in the past, although the game didn't crash on me while I was playing it in the past hour. However, I wouldn't rule out a crash yet. // On another note, I noticed during the startup log of the game, there were a few errors, and I wondered if these may be more insightful to diagnosing the issue. You can see them [here](http://newpaste.md-5.net/p7qaj0evk).

Comment: And I've been trying to figure this out for months, no idea why I never found that. I've been thinking it was an issue with my graphics card, and I've been trying thing after thing with drivers for my graphics card, to no avail.

Comment: Not sure why it's trying to load `swrast` first, but it seems to fail. What happens when you run `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo`? Can you post that output?

Comment: If this makes sense to you, I'll be impressed. It put out this crazy long output for that command; you can see it [here](http://newpaste.md-5.net/pxibcx4yv).

Comment: Also, I just now tried booting up the game and I crashed a few minutes in. I put the crash log after doing the fix you described [here](http://newpaste.md-5.net/pxkykfkv5).

Comment: @jflory7 come to [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) and we can discuss in real-time. Yes I am able to interpret that glxinfo log. It seems like you do not have any hardware-accelerated 3D drivers installed (or they are not installed *correctly*). This may well be a separate problem from your crashes, or it could possibly (though, not likely) be the cause of them. If it were a graphics related heap corruption, though, ASLR would cause it to crash in a different place each time, not in the same exact (sound-related!) lib. So I'm still leaning toward it being sound

Comment: **BUT** you should also, unrelatedly, fix your graphics drivers so you can actually take advantage of the hardware acceleration of your GPU :P

Comment: It's likely that they're not done correctly, in addition to the sound. I have had a very hard time getting my graphics drivers installed. :P I will hop on Root Access now.